# Create MS Access query objects through Perl

Tags: perl, ms-access

I want to create MS Access query object through Perl. I can query on tables but not able to find how to access already existing query objects present in Access database.

I also want to create new query objects through Perl and save it with a name.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You can access Access queries by using a COM Object

Comment: Thanks for your comment but can you be more specific? Is there any Perl module?

Comment: You can use [`Win32::OLE`](http://search.cpan.org/~jdb/Win32-OLE-0.1709/lib/Win32/OLE.pm).

Answer (score 0):

The below link may be helpful for you:

[Class::DBI::MSAccess](https://metacpan.org/module/Class%3a%3aDBI%3a%3aMSAccess)